# How to run the following jQuery code

Tags: jquery, html

My friend gave the following code which is working awesome here http://jsfiddle.net/WVLE2/

I tried the same using a HTML page as below but its not working. I am in learning stage of jQuery. Anybody please help me how to perform chat scrolling in the below script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" ></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js" ></script>
<title>Chat scroll test</title>
<style type="text/css">
#chat
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
</style>
<script>
monitor = function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        wrap = $this.find('.wrapper'),
        height = $this.height(),
        maxScroll = wrap.height() - height,
        top = $this.scrollTop();
    if (maxScroll === top) {
        $this.addClass('atBottom');
    } else {
        $this.removeClass('atBottom');
    }
}
    window.setInterval(function() {
        monitor.call($('#chat').get(0));
    }, 350);
$('#chat').bind('addMessage', function(e, message) {
    var $this = $(this),
        top = $this.scrollTop(),
        scroll = $this.hasClass('atBottom');
    $this.find('.wrapper').append(message);
    if (scroll) {
        var wrap = $this.find('.wrapper'),
            height = $this.height(),
            maxScroll = wrap.height() - height
        $this.scrollTop(maxScroll);
    }
})
$('button').click(function() {
    $('#chat').trigger('addMessage', 'asdgagasdg<br/>');
});

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="chat">
    <div class="wrapper">
        adsgasgda<br/>
        adsgasg<br/>
        asd<br/>
        adsgasgda<br/>
        adsgasg<br/>
        adsgasgda<br/>
        adsgasg<br/>
        adsgasgda<br/>
        adsgasg<br/>
        adsgasgda<br/>
        adsgasg<br/>
        adsgasgda<br/>
        adsgasg<br/>
        adsgasgda<br/>
        adsgasg<br/>
    </div>
</div>
<button>Add a line</button>
</body>
</html>
```

And this results nothing not even a line adding on button click. The output is just as per HTML but jQuery is not working.

Comment: Do I need any compiler/anything in addition to run jQuery code?

Comment: You inlude jQuery two times. One dev and one minimized. Just min is fine.

Comment: @EmreErkan - Thanks for that Emre. What's the difference between two?

Comment: Their content is same but `.min` is minified. Minification is the practice of removing unnecessary characters from code to reduce its size thereby improving load times. [More info](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#minify)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    /* your jQuery code */
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding it inside `document.ready` might get it to work. You're selecting some stuff right off the bat; you have to wait for the DOM to be ready to do that correctly.

```
jQuery(function($) {

    // your jquery code goes here

});
```

Comment: Found the same from micha. Thanks anyways! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is executing before the document is ready, thus when `$('button').click()` executes, the button does not exist yet so the jQuery function to resolve your selector finds no matching objects and therefore the code does nothing.  You have several options:

1) You can move your `<script>` tags and resulting code after the HTML (at the end of the `<body>`) so that the objects already exist when the code executes.

2) You can wrap your event handler code in a ready handler that waits for the document to be ready before calling your code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // put your code here
});
```

This is similar to using `window.onload = function() {};` to wait for the document to load, but jQuery's method will execute sooner than `window.onload` (jQuery's method doesn't wait for all images to load, just for the DOM to be parsed and ready for manipulation).